# I'm building a touch-screen application for a mobile device. What C++ toolkit should I use?

Tags: c++

Building a touch-screen app for a mobile device, around the size of a book. What C++ toolkit should I use? I was thinking about Qt, or gtkmm with hildon.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably tag your question with the OS, device, mobile, etc., to enhance your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the frameworks that are supported/recommended by the OS on the mobile device.

After that, if you get more than one answer to the above question, check to see which one features the features you want for your application.

After that, pick the one done in the programming language you are most used to.

Good luck.
M.

Answer (score 0):

+1 Qt. Qt's framework is great. and it goes LGPL now.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking into [easyGUI](http://www.easygui.com/). It it can be used with just about any OS and supports just about any device. The only downside is that it costs money.

Answer (score 0):

What I really think you're saying is that you're porting Linux to a completely new device, e.g. one of these electric book things.

I'd suggest you port Android (which is Linux down deep so that part of porting is much the same) and use Java for your UI.